# Mac alias for npm install && bower install

Tags: macos, mac, bashrc

How can I assign this alias to my new mac with Yosemite?

```
alias in = "npm install && bower install"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `alias` directive to your `~/.bashrc` file. You'll need to remove the spaces around the `=` symbol for bash to parse the command correctly:

```
alias in="npm install && bower install"
```

You could allow the caller to specify a package name if you use a shell function instead of an alias. Here we pass the same argument to both `npm` and `bower` (note, use `"$@"` instead of `$1` if there is more than one argument):

```
in() {
    npm install $1 && bower install $1
}
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364259/automating-npm-install-bower-install-dev-with-generator-angular-for-yeoma

Comment: do I have to shut all my terminal windows, or open new ones to use this?

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` to take effect in an existing shell.

Comment: I have this: **alias sd=“—save-dev”** but in terminal I type `sd` I get:**-bash: sd: command not found**

Comment: A `bash` alias can only be used as a command, not an argument. To create a shortcut for a command-line option, you would need to use an alias that includes the option (e.g., `alias sd='npm install --save-dev'` or use an environment variable (`export SD='--save-dev'`) and then issue `npm install $SD` which really doesn't save much typing.